# Doctrine - Get items based on the count of a many to many

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following tables, User, Project and Images.

A User has a one to many relationship with Projects and Images. Each Project and Image is owned by a User.

A Project has a many to many relationship with Images. So each Project can have many Images, and an Image can appear within many Projects.

I want to write a DQL query to get all Images, for a specific User that are not included in any Projects. This I can write in SQL.

Is writing in SQL the best way to go?

Or should I be using DQL to do this?

I have tried writing the DQL but its hard work!

**Edit**

From within my Image Repo I am now doing this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("i");

$qb->select("i")
    ->from('MyBundleName:User','u')
    ->innerJoin('u.images', 'user_images')
    ->where('IDENTITY(u.id) = :user_id')
    ->andWhere('NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT p
        FROM MyBundleName:Project p
        WHERE user_images MEMBER of p.images
    )')
->setParameter('user_id', $user_id);
```

I have replace the `/` syntax with `:` for my classes as they failed when using `/`

I am still getting this error though;

> [Semantical Error] line 0, col 131 near 'id) = :user_id': Error:
>   Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.

The function `createQueryBuilder` requires an alias, I am passing it `"i"` - is that right?

I then give it `"i"` again when calling `select`?

If I remove the `innerJoin` then it works, but the results are wrong. It returns all images even if they do exist within an project.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say how difficult it would be in DQL, but I can tell you that in SQL it sounds pretty simple:

```
SELECT I.*
FROM IMAGES I
INNER JOIN USERS U ON (I.USER_ID = U.USER_ID)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   PROJECTS P, PROJECT_IMAGES PI
    WHERE  P.USER_ID = U.USER_ID
    AND    PI.PROJECT_ID = P.PROJECT_ID
    AND    I.IMAGE_ID = PI.IMAGE_ID
)
```

Images owned by a user which does not exist in any project that the user owns.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your entities look like but given the relations something like this should work. The key is combining `NOT EXISTS` and `MEMBER OF` (you want to make sure that for all returned images no project exists that the image is a member of).

```
$qb->select("i")
    ->from('MyBundle\Entity\User','u')
    ->innerJoin('u.images','i')
    ->where('IDENTITY(u) = :user_id')
    ->andWhere('NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT p
        FROM MyBundle\Entity\Project p 
        WHERE i MEMBER of p.images
      )')
    ->setParameter('user_id', $user_id);
```

Comment: This looks good, but I am getting this `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 99 near 'u) = :user_i': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a SingleValuedAssociationField.`

Comment: Try replacing `IDENTITY(u)` with `u.id`

Comment: Tried that and get the same. I think I have bigger issues though as the project is running version 2.1

Comment: If I am placing this within an existing Entity's Repo class, which class would I place it into? Looking at your example I am guessing the Image Repo?

Comment: @JakeN since the query returns `Image` entities, that's the repo I would place it in but if you use full class names in your `from`, then I don't think it matters

Comment: thanks again, made an edit based on your suggestion. But I think I have cracked it. Will report back again soon. Thanks again.